# app.post not working, prints nothing using console.log. Appreciate your help. ( Learning Express Node JS)

Tags: node.js, forms, express, console, nodemon

I'm using node.js and express, in post request not working
and  prints nothing using console.log. Appreciate your help

The following code is app.json file

```
const express = require("express");
const app=express();
const https=require("https");
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
});
app.post("/", function(req, res){
console.log("test")
})
app.listen(3000, function (req, res) {
  console.log("Server is running at port 3000");
})
```

The following code is html file

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <form action="/" method="POST">
    <label for="cityInput">City</label>
    <input id="cityInput" type="text" name="City">
    <button type="button" name="Submit">Go</button>
  </form>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The following code is package.json file

```
{

  "name": "weathersearch",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "weather.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: hey @vik, if you're accessing your page using GET then you won't see the console. You'll see it if you send a request using POST. Your form will by default send a GET request to the server that's why you're not seeing anything in the console.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you forget the "form" tag wrapper?
2. Change type button to submit
3. Add action and method in **form** tag

Try this one:

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <label for="cityInput">City</label>
    <input id="cityInput" type="text" name="City">
    <button type="submit" name="Submit">Go</button>
</form>
```